# How to flush Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, logging, xamarin.ios, serilog

In the [README for Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin) it says:

> Because the memory buffer may contain events that have not yet been written to the target sink, it is important to call Log.CloseAndFlush() or Logger.Dispose() when the application/activity exits.

What's the recommended way to do this on iOS? One of the AppDelegate methods like `OnResignActivation` or `DidEnterBackground`? If I use `OnResignActivation` or `DidEnterBackground` does that mean that I'll have to create a new instance of the logger on the `OnActivated` or `WillEnterForeground` methods every time?